# How to set 3 consecutive position of array an RGB values in a loop

Tags: java, arrays

Ive defined a color module that does some basic operations on RGB vectors.

Im trying to export an image in java after applying some operations on the RGB values of each pixel. I have an array the size of: height*width which I'm iterating it in a loop, the code snippet that does that:

```
byte[] rgbData = new byte[this.imageWidth * this.imageHeight * 3];
for (int x = 0; x < this.imageWidth; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < this.imageHeight; y++) {
        Color color=this.scene.getPixelColor(x, y, this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
        rgbData[(y * this.imageWidth + x) * 3] = color.getRedByte();
        rgbData[(y * this.imageWidth + x) * 3 + 1] = color.getGreenByte();
        rgbData[(y * this.imageWidth + x) * 3 + 2] = color.getBlueByte();

    }
}
```

I'm trying to set all 3 RGB values in one line.
something like (just a pseudo code):

```
byte[] rgbData = new byte[this.imageWidth * this.imageHeight * 3];
for (int x = 0; x < this.imageWidth; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < this.imageHeight; y++) {
        Color color=this.scene.getPixelColor(x, y, this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
        rgbData[(y * this.imageWidth + x) * 3 <0:2>] =color.returnRGB()
    }
}
```

Im having difficulties in 2 issues:

1. how to perform that operation on the array?
2. how to implement the method returnRGB() in module color?

Will appreciate some help,
Thanks

Comment: There's no syntax in Java for that.  Why is it important to you?

Comment: @MattTimmermans I found it strange because im coming from python background. so it is more appealing to me to perform such things in a one line instead the way ive already implemented it.

Comment: Java is a lot more verbose than Python is, you will just have to adjust to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this in Java is to take a cue from `InputStream.read(buf,off,len)` and other common methods that produce output into arrays.

Your `returnRGB` method would be like this:

```
Color
{
...
    public void getRGBBytes(byte[] dest, int offset)
    {
        dest[offset++] = redValue;
        dest[offset++] = greenValue;
        dest[offset] = blueValue;
    }
}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
color.getRGBBytes(rgbdata, (y * this.imageWidth + x) * 3);
```

This kind of style is used often where performance is important, because it avoids creating temporary objects.  Those are usually the same situations in which raw arrays are used, so it's an appropriate concern.

I should mention, however, that normally an image processing loop would also be implemented without creating temporary objects -- your requirement to get a color object for each pixel makes this loop a lot slower than it should be.

It would be more efficient to implement this method in whatever class you use for `scene`, so you could do this, and avoid the creation of temporaries altogether:

```
this.scene.getPixelRGBBytes(x, y, rgbdata, (y * this.imageWidth + x) * 3);
```

Comment: Ok, so both ways (the one you suggest and the one I used) are equivalent in a way. But yours is more efficient? am I right?; also would appreciate an upvote.

Comment: My way is not necessarily much more efficient than the code you wrote to fill the array, but it's easier to write and has fewer opportunities for errors made by the caller.  It is more efficient than returning the values together in some kind of packet.

Comment: It involves only one method call and it doesn't calculate the index three times, so it's more efficient in that way. Compared to a method that returns RGB in an array, this avoids creating a throwaway array. In the end, efficiency of code is relevant only after it has been measured to be inefficient.

Comment: THe use of `offset++` in the last row is not necessary, it can be replaced with `dest[offset] = blueValue;`  Additionally you are not passing redValue, greenValue and bluValue

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO `redValue`, `greenValue`, and `blueValue` are assumed to be members of the `Color` class, or they can be replaced with whatever expressions are appropriate

Comment: @MattTimmermans it is not a good idea to put in the color class the implementation to operate on an external array of bytes that is not related to the Color class. It has to be added in an external class, eventually in the class holding the array that uses the color to set part of itself. Additionally this is not a get function, eventually it is a set function because it does not return nothing but it changes values

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO I disagree, but comments in SO are not meant for debates

Answer (score 1):

If the color is represented as an array of int [R, G, B], You could copy an array of values inside another array using the method [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)):

> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the specified position, to the specified position of the destination array. A subsequence of array components are copied from the source array referenced by src to the destination array referenced by dest. The number of components copied is equal to the length argument. The components at positions srcPos through srcPos+length-1 in the source array are copied into positions destPos through destPos+length-1, respectively, of the destination array.

The problem here is that you are using the class Color that doesn't offer such functionality (probably it is different from the equivalent implementation in python) so you need to access each color with a different method and you can't do all in one line without creating a not necessary array of int and using it to do that.

Another possibility similar to the one written by Matt but syntactically correct is

```
public void setRGB(byte[] dest, int offset, byte red, byte green, byte blue) {
    dest[offset] = red;
    dest[offset + 1] = green;
    dest[offset + 2] = blue;
}
```

Here we are using `offset`, `offset + 1` and `offset + 2` that points to the fact that red is put in the first position, green in the second and blue in the third.

Additionally you have to pass red, green, blue as parameters.

An interesting version of setRGB using System.arraycopy can be done using the `...` symbol, so it appears as a one line code:

```
public void setRGB(byte[] dest, int offset, byte... values) {
    System.arraycopy(values, 0, dest, offset, values.length());
}
```

Comment: I see, So if ill return from the Color.returnRGB() an array of size 3 it is possible to do the following: rgbData[(y * this.imageWidth + x) * 3] =color.returnRGB() and it will copy all 3 values? {of course using System.arraycopy}

Comment: @MoonCake yes, you can use `System.arraycopy`, and obviously you have to respect its conventions that you can find in the javadoc

Comment: Great, nice to get familiar with more java functionality; also I will appreciate an upvote.

Comment: @MoonCake I added the version using the `Syste.arraycopy`